# Standard defining whether to strip multi-core cables inside the cable duct or close to IO Card

Tags: cables, standard, wire-terminals, iec

During the factory acceptance test (FAT) of a remote IO panel (24V, atex zone 1,) the client did not accept that the multi-core cables were stripped inside the panel wire duct. He said that they should be stripped only close to the IO Card. I do understand that not mixing thin conductors with thick multi-core cables inside the cable duct is better for maintenance since it reduces the risk of breaking the thin conductors when moving around the thick multi-core cables. However, to be able to request the remote IO panel supplier to fix this, I need to be based on some electrical standard. Are you aware of any electrical standards that back up his statement?

[image: drawing showing what the client wanted vs what was done]

Comment: Welcome! Is it an ATEX requirement?

Comment: @winny So far, he said only that all the panels he commissioned were like this. Regarding ATEX requirements, we are normally guided by the IEC 60079-14, but I couldn't find anything regarding this there.

Comment: Why don't you ask your customer what requirement they are basing this demand on?